# How to use variable in sed command to replace a property value in a property file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, centos6

i can able to use the below command to change value of target by means of hard coding.

```
sed -ie s/^target=.*/target=google.com/ url.properties
```

But if i used variable i am getting error. I dont know how sed commands all working. I only needed to set build system thats it.

```
url = google.com
sed -ie s/^target=.*/target=$url/ url.properties
```

the error is 
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be happening because your `URL` may contain `/` which bash interprets as sed syntax, so something like `https/www.google.com` ends up something like :

```
sed -ie 's/^target=.*/target=https/www.google.com/' url.properties
```

I will suggest to delimit any special characters to avoid `sed` to be confused :

```
url=google.com
url=`echo $url | sed -e "s/\//\\\\\\\\\//g"` # delimits backslash in URL's
sed -ie "s/^target=.*/target=$url/" url.properties
```

Comment: Or use different delimiters for the `s///` command: `sed -i "s#target=.*#target=$url#" file`

Comment: yeah that's also one way but URL can also contain `#` symbol.

Comment: url=`echo $url | sed -e "s/\//\\\\\//g"` getting error as sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @user3551469 can you give me the value of `url`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- You can't have spaces in variable assignments in bash
- You must quote the `sed` command (and ideally the url too)

Working example:

```
url="google.com"
sed -ie "s/^target=.*/target=$url/" url.properties
```